# Windows 10 failed boot after insider update

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-update, windows-insider

The device is a Surface Pro.

After updating Windows 10 and rebooting, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Using `F8` or `Shift + F8` does not enter recovery mode.

Booting from a stick with Windows 10 and then running:

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

throws a permission error on `bootrec /FixBoot`.

Using Fix boot from the repair options of the USB gives the message that it was not possible to fix the boot:

[image]

### Update

If I try a system restore there are 2 options to restore from and for both options it gives the error: `No restore points have been createdon your computer's system drive.`

Uninstall latest quality or feature update are both failing.

Comment: While using the usb, does it give you the option to unistall a recent update applied?, maybe you could try that

Comment: @TamalesRancheros It does, but I need the upgrade done otherwise I would have done that. My fault for not mentioning that.

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda - You should uninstall the most recent update.  You need to get your machine working. Once it's working we can help you install the Insider Preview build.

Comment: @Ramhound what would be the next steps after uninstalling the insider update?

Comment: You should be able to restart normally. If not, can you restore at an earlier date?

Comment: @Didier I need this insider update done, I can't just rollback without a way to install the insider updates.

Comment: Well, right now, your machine is unusable, so maybe uninstalling the faulty update (maybe KB4550945? It's caused a lot of damage on PCs, lately) could make it usable again, and THEN you'd be able to upgrade to the latest Insider build. Up to you. If you've got System Restore enabled, you could go back in time, and try to install your build again.

Comment: @Didier - **The author's problem is not caused by KB4550945**

Comment: We don't know that. One of my PC was renderered useless after the third reboot after installing a faulty KB, so that's no exact science, I'm afraid. OP, here's what you can try, but there's no guarantee it'll work (won't hurt, though): reboot from the USB stick with your installer on it, choose Repair, then open a Command Line and type "bootsect /nt60 sys" (no quotes), then press Enter. You should get a "Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes" return, and then you can exit the installer and restart. Worst case, you type "bootsect /nt60 all /force".

Comment: Ok, I will give reverting and re-updating a try.

Comment: @Didier - **I know for a fact that KB4550945 is unrelated to the author's problem.**  I have more experience with Windows, any issues with KB4550945 would have surfaced before the author installed the Insider Preview feature update.

Comment: I added an update with more things I tried.